# Can't disable fullscreen from i3 script

Tags: chrome, i3

I use an i3 binding to execute the script

```
#!/bin/sh
i3-msg workspace web
/bin/chromium --start-fullscreen
sleep 5
i3-msg fullscreen disable
```

The last two lines are to disable the fullscreen (I don't know if the sleeping is necessary). The i3 fullscreen is enabled as a side-effect of the argument to chromium (which is intended to hide the address bar etc. only). But for some reason, it doesn't work, the fullscreen is not disabled. Only if I use the binding $mod+f to toggle fullscreen manually is it disabled. Why doesn't the script manage to do this?

(The reason I want to disable fullscreen is that, when I use chromium-vim to edit a text field externally, gvim doesn't show until fullscreen is disabled.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is quite simple, when you run `chromium` it does not return until it finishes, that is after you close *Chromium*. So `sleep` and `i3-msg` will only be run after the window is already gone.

To solve this, you just need to start `chromium` in the background, this can be done by appending `&` to the command. The `sleep` is required, without it `i3-msg` might run before *Chromium* even initialized its window. Five seconds might be a bit long, but it really depends on how fast *Chromium* opens on your system.

Additionally, I would suggest to add criteria to the `i3-msg`. That way it works on any *Chromium* window and not just the currently focused window, which might not actually be the desired *Chromium* window (obviously this might not be a desired behavior, in case you want some *Chromium* windows to be fullscreen).

```
#!/bin/sh
i3-msg workspace web
/bin/chromium --start-fullscreen &
sleep 2
i3-msg '[instance="^chromium$"] fullscreen disable'
```

---

**Alternatively**, if you want *Chromium* windows to always appear on the workspace "web", you can use the `assign` and `for_window` configuration directives in your *i3* configuration to do the work:

```
assign [instance="^chromium$"] web
for_window [instance="^chromium$"] exec "sh -c 'sleep 2; i3-msg \[instance=chromium\] fullscreen disable'"
```

With that, you no longer need a script and every time you run `chromium` *i3* will put it on "web" and two seconds later the window will drop out of fullscreen.
**Note:** Although it is theoretically possible to use `fullscreen disable` directly with `for_window`, it does not work with *Chromium* because the window does actually start in fullscreen. *Chromium* just enables fullscreen really fast; unfortunately *i3* is even faster when running `for_window`. So *i3* will disable fullscreen before *Chromium* even tries to enable it. That is why the detour with running `sleep` and `i3-msg` via `exec` is necessary.